# Why ecs creates volumes inside the container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm using `ecs-cli` to deploy my `docker-compose.yml` to ecs.

Why when I defined volumes `ecs-cli` copy and create files/directories inside the container, rather than in host-ec2-ami? how can I tell the html must be on host-ec2-ami-machine?

**./appsy/dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD ./index.html /content/index.html
```

**./appsy/index.html:**

```
<div> hello</div>
```

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: 0000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/appsy:latest
    volumes:
      - /content:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tell the html must be on host-ec2-ami-machine?

If you want to reference files/directories on the host from within the container, then you did the correct attempt to use `volumes`:
Your `docker-compose.yaml` essentially says "mount host `/content` directory to `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory in your container".

Note, however, in that case copying `index.html` into the container (which you do in your `Dockerfile`) does not make any sense...

Comment: Well, how to copy index file from my local machine to the host with ecs-cli command? is it possible? or should I copy manually the files?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with `ecs-cli`. You should have a good reason to try to copy files to a host (if your cluster consists of >1 node - you don't know which node the container will land on... so you'll have to copy the file to all of the nodes). I would suggest just copy `index.html` straight to `/usr/share/nginx/html/` in your `Dockerfile` during the image build. No volume mounts are needed then.